# how to redirect to a different page on exit using jquery

Tags: jquery, redirect

I came across the below code somewhere that will show an alert message when the browser tab/window is closed or if the back button is pressed. Now I would like to redirect to a different page when the alert message is showing up. 
Ex - we are on page1.html, user tries to close the window or hit back button, then we show "Are you sure want to go away from this page..? " when the message is showing up, on the background I want to redirect to a page2.html. I have this happening using javascript but there is one other issue with that. Please advise how to do this..

this is what I have

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function PopIt() {return "Are you sure you want to leave?"; }
     function UnPopIt()  {} 
     $(document).ready(function() {
     window.onbeforeunload = PopIt;
     $("a").click(function(){ window.onbeforeunload = UnPopIt; });  

     });
</script>
```

I tried adding "`document.location.href="page2.html";"` below return "" line but it did not work..

Comment: Obligatory comment telling you not to do this.  If the user browses to a different page, then let them.

Comment: i see the annoyance, working on a project where i don't have too much control..

Comment: try window.location="page2.html

Comment: @KirenSiva which place? because I tried this before  so i want to make sure exactly where.

Comment: Where you are trying `document.location.href="page2.html"`.I recommended to use this line of code to redirect other page. `window.location.href=window.referer="page2.html"`.